# Family of independent events or sequence of independent events

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, independence

I was reading [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Independent_Events/General_Definition) about the general definition of independent events.  The definition stated there is

> **Independent Events**: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an experiment with probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, Pr)$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_i : i\in I\}$ be a family of events of $\mathcal{E}$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is independent if and only if $\,\,\forall 
>  \,\,\text{finite} \,\,J\subseteq I$ $$Pr\left(\bigcap_{i\in J}A_i\right)=\prod_{i\in J}Pr(A_i)$$

The part that I am concerned about is the initial statement, not the consequence, which I am fine with. The text talks about a family of events being independent. However, always on proofwiki here is the definition of a family ([see here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Indexing_Set)):

> **Indexing Set**: Let $I$ and $S$ be sets.  Let $x: I\longrightarrow S$ be a function. The set $I$ of $x$ is called indexing set of the sequence $\langle x_i \rangle_{i\in I}$.
>
> **Family**: The codomain $S$, consisting of the terms $\langle x_i\rangle_{i\in I}$, along with the indexing function $x$ itself, is called a family of elements of $S$ indexed by $I$.

---

So actually, a family is not just a sequence! But it is a sequence PLUS the indexing function. Then is the "independent events" definition saying that "sequence + indexing function" are independent? Or is it a mistake and they actually meant that only the sequence is independent? Here are my suggestions:

> **Independent Events (only sequence)**: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an experiment with probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, Pr)$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \langle A_i \rangle_{i\in I}$ be a sequence of events of $\mathcal{E}$ indexed by the function $x: I\subseteq \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \Sigma$. Then the sequence $\mathcal{A}$ is independent if and only if $\,\,\forall 
>  \,\,\text{finite} \,\,J\subseteq I$ $$Pr\left(\bigcap_{i\in J}A_i\right)=\prod_{i\in J}Pr(A_i)$$
>
> **Independent Events (family)**: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an experiment with probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, Pr)$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \langle A_i \rangle_{i\in I}$ be a sequence of events of $\mathcal{E}$ indexed by the function $x: I\subseteq \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \Sigma$. Then the family $(\mathcal{A}, x)$ is independent if and only if $\,\,\forall 
>  \,\,\text{finite} \,\,J\subseteq I$ $$Pr\left(\bigcap_{i\in J}A_i\right)=\prod_{i\in J}Pr(A_i)$$

Comment: Surely thought, it can't be $\mathcal{A} = \{A_i : i\in I\}$ as this would be a set, and we would lose the order of the sets, while there should be one.

Comment: Independent events is well defined.  Family means an un-ordered collection, while sequence means the collection is ordered.  Don't try to read anything more into it.